# Как написать Shortcode?

Tags: pdf, ссылки, wordpress

Здравствуйте, дорогие программисты. Надеюсь, вы мне поможете. Спасибо заранее.
У меня нет опыта PHP-программиста, поэтому я обращаюсь к вам.

Мне нужен shortcode в wordpress-е, которая будет ссылкой на PDF file. shortcode будет с определенным style-ом. style у меня уже есть.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // [my_pdf href=http://site.ru/file.pdf text=мой файл]
function pdf_short( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'href' => '',
                'text'=>''
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<a href='".$href.'" class="class" title="title">'. $text .'</a>;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_pdf', 'pdf_short' );
```

Comment: спасибо друг,Благодарность за помощь